# How to prove if the given point is always the circumcenter of the triangle?

Tags: geometry, triangles

In the square $ABCD$, the points $M$ and $N$ belong to the sides $BC$ and $CD$ respectively, such that $\angle MAN = 45^°$. Let $O$ be the point of intersection of the circle that goes through $C$, $M$ and $N$ with the segment $AC$. Is the point $O$ always the circumcenter of $\triangle MAN$?
[image: Illustration on Geogebra]

The image shows $\angle NAD = \theta = 30^°$, but the question goes for all values of $\theta$ ranging from $0^°$ to $45^°$. The calculator suggests that it's true, but I can't find a way to prove it.

I've noticed that since $\angle MCN = 90^°$, the segment $MN$ must be a diameter of the small circle, and thus $\angle MON = 90^°$. If $O$ were to be the circumcenter of $\triangle MAN$, it would obey the rule of angles at the center being twice the angle at the circumference, however I don't know if that means it is necessarily the circumcenter.

Comment: A related question might be: if one angle is always double the other, does this imply that the larger angle is always at the centre of the circle..? If that angle is on the diameter of the circle that passes through both angle apexes, the answer is yes and the proof follows.

Comment: From the label, I'm assuming that you drew the image in Geogebra. Did you test if $O$ is the circumcenter, either in this instance, or as you vary $\theta$?

Comment: @CalvinLin yes, the tests do show that O is the circumcenter for all values of theta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, if $N=D$, then $M=C$ and there are infinitely many different circles that can be drawn through $N$ and $M$. Similarily, if $N$=$C$. Therefore we are going to assume, that $N$ lies between points $D$ and $C$. WLOG $AD=1$. Put $\angle DAN=\theta$, $\angle NMC=\alpha$, $ND=q$, and let $r$ be the radius of the red circle.[image]
$BM=tan(\frac{\pi}{4}-\theta)=\frac{1-tan(\theta)}{1+tan(\theta)}=\frac{1-q}{1+q}$, so $MC=1-\frac{1-q}{1+q}=\frac{2q}{1+q}$ and $CN=1-q$. Pythagoras theorem gives $MN^2=(1-q)^2+(\frac{2q}{1+q})^2=\frac{(1-q^2)^2+4q^2}{(1+q)^2}=\frac{(1+q^2)^2}{(1+q)^2}$, hence $r=\frac{MN}{2}=\frac{1+q^2}{2(1+q)}$. I'm going to switch to the complex plane now with the origin at $A$ and the real axis running along $AD$.[image]

Note that $P=[\frac{1-q}{1+q}+\frac{q}{1+q}]+i[1-\frac{1-q}{2}]=\frac{1}{1+q}+i\frac{1+q}{2}$. Next, let $M'$ be the point obtained by rotating $M$ around $P$ by $\frac{\pi}{2}$ ccw. Since $M=-re^{-i\alpha}+P$, we get $M'=-re^{-i\alpha}e^{\frac{i\pi}{2}}+P=[-rcos(\alpha)+irsin(\alpha)]i+\frac{1}{1+q}+i\frac{1+q}{2}=[-ir\frac{2q}{2r(1+q)}-r\frac{1-q}{2r}]+\frac{1}{1+q}+i\frac{1+q}{2}=[\frac{1}{1+q}+\frac{q-1}{2}]+i[\frac{1+q}{2}-\frac{q}{1+q}]=\frac{1+q^2}{2(1+q)}+i\frac{1+q^2}{2(1+q)}$. Since $Re(M')=Im(M')$, $M'$ is a point that belongs to both the diagonal $AC$ and the red circle. There are precisely 2 such points, namely $O$ and $C$. Clearly, $C=1+i\neq \frac{1+q^2}{2(1+q)}+i\frac{1+q^2}{2(1+q)}$. Thus $M'=O$, so $\angle OPM=\frac{\pi}{2}$. Also, $AO=\sqrt{[Re(M')]^2+[Im(M')]^2}=\sqrt{2}(\frac{1+q^2}{2(1+q)})$. Aplying Pythagoras gives $MO=ON=\sqrt{2}r=\sqrt{2}(\frac{1+q^2}{2(1+q)})$. We therefore conclude that $O$ is the circumcenter of $\triangle MAN$ and the circumradius is $\sqrt{2}(\frac{1+q^2}{2(1+q)})$.